# Packer log-in automation for new machine image post-boot?

Tags: ubuntu, automation, credentials, packer

I'm using [Packer](http://packer.io/) to automate the building of an Ubuntu-12.04.4-lts machine image (currently targeting Virtualbox as the run-time environment). I'm able to get the base machine configured - my `preseed.cfg` file gets read - and Ubuntu installed, but I eventually run into a manual password prompt (see image below).

This is preventing my various post-boot scripts from running, SSH from becoming available, and (most importantly) Packer from running the Vagrant post-processor and creating a Vagrant box out of the system.

How can I automate navigating/fulfilling this initial credential ask?

Thanks a lot.

[image: Manual login credential prompt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are at that stage the SSH Access should already be available.

If you look at the following preseed file you can see that it installs openssh-server and should work from there:

https://github.com/flomotlik/packer-example/blob/master/http/preseed.cfg

Comment: Thanks a lot @Florian - `d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server ntp` ftw. Like most errors, a dumb one! Really helpful though.